# .net MongoDB Driver Bulkwrite to Cosmos MongoDB timing out

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure

I am trying to use the bulkwrite command alongside ReplaceOneModel to batch upsert over 6000 records into our CosmosDB. I have tried batch increments as low as 100 records at a time but I get a timed out exception after about 500 inserts. The RUs on the database is set to 10000. Tried with and without a partition key, and turning off ordered and validation options and still getting the time out exception. I set the connection timeout on the connection string to 5 minutes. I also added in a minute delay between batches but not luck. When inserting records one by one, there are no errors but that batch is taking too long to complete.

Can someone recommend something to try to prevent the timing out to occur?

Comment: Seems like Microsoft recommends stored procedures for batch processing: 
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6435801-batch-operation-support

Is this the direction I need to go forward with? If so, how do I pass in a list of bson documents via the driver?

Comment: Is this one time migration or you looking to create an automated process/job which will be executed based on business need regularly ?

Comment: Ideally this would be executed through a webjob on our app service. The initial load would be unusually large and then subsequent loads should be much smaller. The scheduling would be a daily.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted many millions of documents recently into CosmosDB via Mongo API using the mongoimport tool, with numInsertionWorkers set to 128 and my collection temporarily set to 100,000 RUs. It only took a few minutes. At 10,000 RU using the SQL API I routinely insert ~6000 documents in just a few seconds, so what you are experiencing above is not typical

Is there a particular reason to use bulkWrite? You may achieve your goal if instead you issue individual write operations, but have multiple client writer threads so that you are executing multiple batches in parallel. You will need to tune the number of concurrent writes you perform against your RU to avoid too many 'Request rate large' exceptions.